# f2py with OMP: can't import module, undefined symbol GOMP_*

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, openmp, f2py

I was hoping to use openmp to speed up my Fortran code that I run through f2py. However, after compiling succesfully, I can't import the module in Python.

For a Fortran95 module like this:

```
module test
implicit none
contains
subroutine readygo()
real(kind = 8), dimension(10000) :: q
!$OMP WORKSHARE
q = 7
!$OMP END WORKSHARE
end subroutine
end module
```

Compiled and imported with these commands:

```
f2py -m SOmod --fcompiler=gnu95 --f90flags='-march=native -O3 -fopenmp' -c SOtest.f95
python2 -c "import SOmod"
```

I get an error. The error is for the import - compiling works fine both with f2py or gfortran directly (only get a warning about 'Using deprecated NumPy API').

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./SOmod.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_barrier
```

I get different GOMP_* errors for different OMP directives. Without directives (but with -openmp flag) it works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error on Mac OS X (10.9.5), with `gfortran` installed using homebrew, and I was able to fix it by adding `-lgomp` to the command:

```
f2py -m SOmod --fcompiler=gnu95 --f90flags='-march=native -O3 -fopenmp' -lgomp -c SOtest.f95
```

*Added by @Mark*: Note that `-lgomp` is an argument for f2py, not gfortran. Although it compiles with just `-gomp`, both `-gomp` and `-fopenmp` are needed for it to be parallel, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938238/difference-between-linking-openmp-with-fopenmp-and-lgomp). GOMP is the GNU openMP implementation.

Comment: Works great! I'll add a little info that I found because of your answer, hope that's ok.